# How to know the event by looking at /dev/input/by-id

Tags: linux, drivers, devices, input

I want to access the keyboard device driver. I usually accesses it by looking at
 `/dev/input/by-name` but the event provided by it gets changed every time I log in.

After searchin on the Net, I found that this problem can be removed if I use `/by-id` but I am unable to find any device there in that folder.